# How to add deleted value into a new array and print them

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method that allows removing the publication by a specific year.
However, I want to put all the publication which I will be removed into a new array and print them.

Any suggestion or help?
Thank you.

```
enter code here 
public void removeYear(int removeYear)
{   
    Iterator<Publication> pb = publicationList.iterator();
    while(pb.hasNext()){
        Publication publication = pb.next();
        if(publication.getYear() == removeYear){
    
            pb.remove();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: If publications are frequently searched for by year, have you considered using a Map<Year, List<Publication>>?. It would greatly simplify what you're looking for here and in other related methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First what you should do is change the return type of the method to List because besides the deleting part we also want to save data to a new `List` so when calling this method it will return a List with the deleted data.

```
 public List<Publication> removeYear(int removeYear){
```

And you have to declare a new List of Publication inside the method, so there we can save the deleted Publications

```
List<Publication> listNew = new ArrayList<>();
```

And we simply save the object with the `add()` method

```
 listNew.add(publication);
```

All the code

```
public List<Publication> removeYear(int removeYear){
    Iterator<Publication> pb = publicationList.iterator();
    List<Publication> listNew = new ArrayList<>();
    while(pb.hasNext()){
        Publication publication = pb.next();
        if(publication.getYear() == removeYear){
            listNew.add(publication);
            pb.remove();

        }
    }
return listNew;
}
```

Here we have returned a new list with deleted Publications.

And later if you want to print it simply call the method

```
List<Publication> deletedList = classIntance.removeYear(2000);
```

And print it

```
 System.out.println("Deleted Publication are");
    deletedList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Do not return `ArrayList<...>`. Return a `List<...>` instead.

Comment: Changed it @ETO, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach may not be optional but seems to be a bit cleaner:

- filter out the publications to be deleted by year
- Use `List::removeAll` to complete removal:

```java
public void removeYear(int removeYear) {
    List<Publication> toDelete = publicationList.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getYear() == removeYear)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // use publications from `toDelete` as needed
    // ...
    publicationList.removeAll(toDelete);    
}
```

---

Another approach may be based on using [`Collectors.partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-) collector which would split the list into two parts by predicate value:

```java
public void removeYear(int removeYear) {
    Map<Boolean, Publication> partitioned = publicationList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(p.getYear() == removeYear));

    System.out.println("deleted publications: " + partitioned.get(true));

    // keep publications without the removeYear
    publicationList = partitioned.get(false);
}
```